# React child state vs props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I've been researching React props and state and currently I am using Redux. I have been trying to figure out how to keep my components reusable and I have a problem with a specific component.

Basically it functions like gmail with the checkboxes on the side and function appear based on what is selected, you are also able to pass in buttons for functions to show. However I am having a problem with the selections. So for the component to work correctly I have to have a selected attribute but I do not want this attribute in the props because it only pertains to this component everything else will be in the props. How do I handle this because I know your not supposed to change props within a component?

Below is an example if I use only state and its not reusable:

```
this.state = {
        selectAll: false,
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                description: "Description 1",
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                description: "Description 2",
                selected: true
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                description: "Description 3",
                selected: false
            },
        ],
        listDetails: {
            start: 1,
            end: 50,
            currentPage: 1,
            lastPage: 2,
        },
        toolbarActions: [
            {
                icon: "edit",
                useOnMultiple: true,
                use: true,
                handleFunctionSingle: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Edit Single"),
                handleFunctionMultiple: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Edit Multiple"),
            },
            {
                icon: "trash",
                useOnMultiple: true,
                use: true,
                handleFunctionSingle: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Delete Single"),
                handleFunctionMultiple: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Delete Multiple"),
            }
        ],
    }
```

So with this example everything would be passed in except for the selectAll state and the selected within the objects of list.

This would be the props passed in

```
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                description: "Description 1",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                description: "Description 2",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                description: "Description 3",
            },
        ],
        listDetails: {
            start: 1,
            end: 50,
            currentPage: 1,
            lastPage: 2,
        },
        toolbarActions: [
            {
                icon: "edit",
                useOnMultiple: true,
                use: true,
                handleFunctionSingle: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Edit Single"),
                handleFunctionMultiple: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Edit Multiple"),
            },
            {
                icon: "trash",
                useOnMultiple: true,
                use: true,
                handleFunctionSingle: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Delete Single"),
                handleFunctionMultiple: this.handleActionsFunction.bind(this, "Delete Multiple"),
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Does anything else need access to the state of this thing? Can it be set from other components? Does a state change in this component trigger changes or cause a need to re-render other components that don't descend from this one? `this.state` is only for the equivalent of 'private' properties. Also, you mention Redux but I don't see any Reduxing going on in what you posted...

Comment: Also, doing things for the sake of code reuse is vastly overrated. Much, much needless complexity has been added to code for the sake of speculative re-use that ends up being impractical or impossible. Once you notice a recurring pattern in your code, *then* you refactor to abstract out that part. Favor duplication over premature abstraction.

Comment: Yeah, I know this component will be reused because this is application 1 of 4 that will use the same "Action list" functionalities. Other than that everything in that state will be passed minus the selectAll and the selected within the list. I haven't yet moved these value to redux to be passed in which is why I was researching how to handle this senario with certain attributes only being needed for this component.

Comment: I left this vague because I may not be doing this correctly and I just want to focus on the correct way to use props and have attributes added during the use in the component.

Comment: Basically what I did to solve this and I dont know if its the right way or not but, I created a state in the child element with and array. This array get items pushed or removed if they are selected and thats how I am using the props for the component and the component populate the state it needs.

Comment: If your question is about the "right" way to do it, unless the "right" way has a strong objective component, it's off-topic for stack overflow.